# JSOUP get all information starts with

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsoup

```html
<li data-id="63947814" data-author="ac ca" data-author-id="1387539" data-flags="share report vote" data-isfavorite="false" data-favorite-count="22" data-seyler-slug="" data-comment-count="0">
<div class="content"> el kadar bebelere üstelik hükümetin kıymetlisi olan bir vakıfta tecavüz edilirken üç maymunu oynayan adalet sistemimizin annenin terliğine takılması '' ... sürecek kadar akıl yok'' dedirtiyor..
 <br/>ve bazı malların arzusu gerçek olursa bu sığırlar idam kararları alacaklar, kimi asacaklar ki acaba..
 <br/>bilmem anlatabiliyor muyum? 
</div>
<footer>
 <div class="feedback"></div>
 <div class="info"> <a class="entry-date permalink" href="/entry/63947814">07.11.2016 12:29</a> <a class="entry-author" href="/biri/ac-ca">ac ca</a> </div>
</footer>
<div class="comment-summary">
 <div class="comment-pages"> </div>
</div>
</li>
```

I've got this html code.My question is i want to parse it with JSOUP like : i will get all li data-id=* informations.This website contains random data-id's so all i just wants get data starts with anything "li data-id="

`Elements links = document.select("li[data-id=63947814]");`
it's works only got id "63947814".

i've tried "*" : `Elements links = document.select("li[data-id=*]");`or

```
  Elements links = document.select("li[data-id=\"*\"]");
```

but it doesnt work.Searched JSON API's and didn't get all i wanted.

so much thanks.

Comment: this should work `document.select("li[data-id]")`

Comment: Try this add the `*` before the  `=`  `document.select("li[data-id*=somename]")`

Comment: @prasad
it doesn't work

Comment: @Satpal
it does work perfectly,thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`Attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Attribute_Selectors), it will select all the elements with `data-id` attribute.

```
Elements links = document.select("li[data-id]");
```